# How to generate SWT paint event at startup

Tags: java, events, canvas, swt, paint

I have a SWT application which displays and sorts image files by renaming the file.  Scruffy I know, but the sorted-by-name files are the input for a later step that I cannot change.

So far I have the UI almost working but the initial image at startup does not generate a paint event, so the `Canvas` is blank.  If I minimally resize the window, it immediately appears correctly.  I am trying (perhaps incorrectly) to generate the event explicitly using the `notifyListeners()` method of `Canvas` which needs to be passed a `PaintEvent` and I am stuck on how to instantiate one.

What is the correct way to force this initial event to be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly fire a `PaintEvent`. Instead use one, or combination, of the below options:

- `layout()` marks forces the repositioning of all composite-children.
  This will become visible on next repaint, which will be done
  somewhere in the future, when composite's screen-area will be redrawn
- `redraw()` marks the widget an invalidated. On next
  redraw-system-action this area will be repainted.
- `update()` forces all outstanding redraw() requests to be completed
  NOW.

Comment: An asyncExec() with a redraw() inside it worked. layout() did not work.

Comment: @casgage You'd have to call `layout()` (or even `layout(true, true)`) on the parent of your canvas. But `redraw` will do fine in this case.